# A generic error occurred in GDI+ (not memory streams)

Tags: c#, image, gdi

I am getting the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
    at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
    at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
```

The code is as follows:

```
public void foo()
{
    Image label = generateLabel(maxResolution.X, maxResolution.Y);
    label.Save(Path.Combine(Settings.LabelDirectory, currentDespatch.SalesOrderNumber + "-" + currentDespatch.DespatchNumber + ".png"), ImageFormat.Png);
}

 private Image generateLabel(int dpix, int dpiy)
{

    var ratio = 2;

    var margin = 50*ratio;

    // The printer defaults to 100 pixels per inch, hence 600x400 for a 6x4 label
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(600*ratio, 400*ratio);

    img.SetResolution(dpix, dpiy);

    var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    Image barcode = Barcode.DoEncode(TYPE.CODE39, currentDespatch.SalesOrderNumber, true, 325*ratio, 140*ratio);            

    canvas.Clear(Color.White);
    canvas.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    canvas.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(barcode, new Rectangle(img.Width - barcode.Width - (margin/4), margin, barcode.Width, barcode.Height));

    Font font = new Font("Arial", 17*ratio, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    Font small = new Font("Arial", 14*ratio, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    canvas.DrawString("Hello world", font, brush, margin, img.Height - margin - (margin*2/3));
    canvas.DrawString("From label", small, brush, margin, img.Height - margin);
    canvas.Save();

    return img;
}
```

Most of the answers I've found so far relate to memory streams, which I am not using, hence why I am puzzled.

I think it's something to do with GC collecting some object before I manage to save the image, but it's not obvious to me where the culprit lies.

The failure is intermittent, as it succeeds most of the time, and then fails every now and then, so it's not permission related.

This is the barcode library being used: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20823/Barcode-Image-Generation-Library

Comment: what if you were to wrap our objects around a using statement to hand the auto Disposing this is the only thing I can think of looking at your code

Comment: Barcodes of type Code 39 allow for some special characters including the forward slash "/".
Your code uses the same barcode string in the output file name. If one of the file name characters is "/", Image.Save might throw a similar exception.

Comment: No, the order number never has slashes.

Comment: It could still be a problem related to the file name or some other permissions issue.
To rule that out, test this code instead of the path you're currently using:  
    //first save a dummy small bitmap to make sure the path is OK
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(4, 4, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    bmp.SetPixel(2, 2, Color.GreenYellow);
    bmp.Save(@"d:\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    MessageBox.Show(@"check the file d:\test.png then click OK");
    //then save the image you generated using your generateLabel() function
    label.Save(@"d:\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);